# How do I create a file that doesn't contain information older than 5 minutes?

Tags: python, file, text-files, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I'm working on Twitter Streaming api to get live tweets data.

I can print that data to console. But what I want is to save the data to a file and that data shouldn't be older than 5 minutes.

How do I continuously roll the file that holds the data from last 5 minutes as we can do for log files.

At the same time the file should be accessible for reading.

Is there any way to do that in Python?

I haven't come across such thing where we can mention such duration for which the file can hold specific data.

Comment: Create a data structure of all the entries that you want to keep within the active window, and flush that data structure regularly to the same file and overwrite the file’s content with every flush.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. It looks like you want to use the file as a communication between two processes? As you mentioned you want to have simultaneous read/write? If not, there is probably a better way to approach.

Comment: I'm working on analyzing the stream data in the last 5 minutes. I guess I need to save it somewhere and read from there to create a report from tweets for every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A search for "python logrotate" finds this: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler.
It is probably worth giving a try.

If you'd rather code something yourself, managing the tweets in memory (with a `collections.deque` for example so it's easy to pop old ones and append new ones), then flush this to file once in a while..., (or use sockets, pickle, simply the variable name to pass this data to your analysis function, as already mentioned in other answers).

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. It kills the tweet from the list whenever its age had exceeded 300 seconds.

```
import time;
TIME_LIMIT = 300; # 5 mins in seconds


# Get the tweet text and the time stamp
def GetTweet():
    #...
    # Wait until there is a new tweet from Donald :)
    text = 'your function that gets the text goes here';

    # Get the time stamp
    time_ = time.time();
    return text, time_


# Kill all the old data that is older than X seconds
def KillOldTweet(tweets):
    time_now = time.time();  # Capture the current time

    # For every tweet stored remove the old one
    for i, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
        time_diff = time_now - tweet[1]; # get the time difference
        if time_diff > TIME_LIMIT: # if older than X secods, kill that tweet from the list
            tweets.pop(i);
            pass;      
        pass;

    return tweets; # return the list

# Updates the file with the list of text of tweets
def UpdateFile(tweets):
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:  # open the file and close it after writing
        texts = [ i for i, j in tweets ]; # unzip;
        out_text = str(texts); # convert to string
        print(out_text); #
        file.write(out_text); # overwrite to file
        pass;
    pass;


tweets = [];
while(1):
    # Get the new tweet and append to the list
    text, time_ = GetTweet(); # Wait until a new tweet arrived
    tweet = (text, time_); # zip it into a tuple
    tweets.append(tweet); # append it to list


    # Kill the old tweets from the list
    tweets = KillOldTweet(tweets)

    # Update the file with the fresh tweets
    UpdateFile(tweets);

    # Sleep for 1 second.
    time.sleep(1);

    pass;
```

But I would recommend you using socket module instead of writing to a text file. Or use the pickle module to easily unpack stuff from the file

Answer (score -1):

Save the data in a file, with the actual time and check to see if the actual time is different by 5 min. Use time. Or use the sleep function and erase old data each 5 min.